# add complete address in default columns in order grid

Tags: magento, grid

I want to add complete address in default "Bill to Name" and "Ship to Name" columns in order grid in Magento admin.
I am attaching screen-shot for more explanation.
[image]
Please suggest me how can I achieve this?

Comment: please check this http://www.ecomdev.org/2010/07/27/adding-order-attribute-to-orders-grid-in-magento-1-4-1.html

Comment: thanks for quick response, but I have already checked this article. it's not fulfill my requirement. actually I want to replace "Bill to Name" and "Ship to Name" columns with full address columns.

Comment: means you have write billing address and shipping address ?in their

Comment: yes, exactly! I want add complete billing address and shipping address in columns

Answer (score 1):

You can override the following class

```
 Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
```

now add the data by using **renderer** as you have access to order, get order id and load the shipping and billing addresses

```
   $order->getShippingAddress()
   $order->getBillingAddress()
```

Implement Renderer :

```
    class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_Billing extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
    {
 public function render(Varien_Object $row)
{

$order_id =  $row->getId();
    $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($order_id);
    $billing_address = $order->getBillingAddress();
return $billing_address;

}
```

}

In Grid file :

```
    $this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),
        'index' => 'billing_name',
        'renderer'  => 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_Billing',
    ));
```

Comment: How can I add renderer in "Bill to Name" and "Ship to Name" columns?

Comment: you will need to define a renderer class, from which you can return 'customized data' related to that order, and call this class to Grid column